# ffmpeg or libav to create audio recording webapp?

Tags: ffmpeg, audio-recording, libav

Is it possible to create a web application which can record audio or video using ffmpeg or libav?

Or are these only for creating desktop aplications for encoding, decoding, recording audio/video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what platforms you are interested in.

Only PC? You can use ffmpeg or libav, but you'll need to create separate plugin for different web-browsers. Alternatives are Flash or signed Java applet loading a native module from a server.

On mobile platforms Flash is not an option usually. Usual approach is to provide a stand-alone application.

Comment: Thnx @Andy T..Do you know of any links from where I can learn about ffmpeg or libav to create audio/video recording web app for different browsers..?

Comment: there're no good documentation for them. Actually, you have two tasks: to implement a core module that performs recording itself and wrappers to plug it in different browsers. those tasks are completely independent